# Probability question confusion

Tags: probability

A bag consists 20 cards contains 4 cards of each Colours, red , green , blue , yellow and white . The four cards of Each Colour are numbered 1,2,3,4 respectively . One card is selected at random . Find the probability that it is a red card or a yellow card with an even number .

How do I do this ? Can I get a hint . Thanks !

Comment: Ambiguous question.    Do you mean a (red card) or a (yellow card with an even number) or do you mean a (red card or a yellow card) with an even number?  The answers will be different.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: How many cards satisfy the condition of being a red card or yellow card with an even number?

Divide that number by 20.

One possible confusion that I have is what is the question asking.

(a red card) or (a yellow card with an even number)?

or

(a red card or a yellow card) with an even number.

But the issue is no longer mathematical but rather an English problem. Once we resolve the problem, you can answer the maths problem.